How to normalize existing data efficiently?
I have several flat tables which I want to normalize. A simple example would be the "source_data" table split into person and address tables and setting the correct foreign address key in the person:
create table source_data (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  person_1_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  person_1_street VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  person_1_city VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  person_2_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  person_2_street VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  person_2_city VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

create table address (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  street VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  city VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

create table person (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  address_id INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (address_id) REFERENCES address(id)
);

insert into source_data (person_1_name, person_1_street, person_1_city, person_2_name, person_2_street, person_2_city)
values ('John Doe', '123 Main St', 'Springfield', 'Jane Doe', '456 Elm St', 'Springfield'),
       ('Alice Smith', '789 Oak St', 'Springfield', 'Bob Smith', '101 Pine St', 'Springfield'),
       ('Charlie Brown', '135 Maple St', 'Springfield', 'Lucy Brown', '246 Birch St', 'Springfield');

I would expect to use a CTE, where I get the created address IDs back and can then use them in the insert for the person table.
Technically that works, but Postgres "unpacks" the address ids in a way m x n persons are created - which is obviously not what I want in this case.
with insert_first_address as (
  insert into address (street, city)
  select person_1_street, person_1_city
  from source_data
  returning id
),
insert_second_address as (
  insert into address (street, city)
  select person_2_street, person_2_city
  from source_data
  returning id
),
insert_first_person as (
  insert into person (name, address_id)
  select s.person_1_name, i.id
  from source_data s, insert_first_address i
  returning id
)
insert into person (name, address_id)
select s.person_2_name, i.id
from source_data s, insert_second_address i
returning id;

I cannot join the address table for inserting into the person table, as the address table created new ids (as I have a 1:2 relationship and in my real scenario I have multiple tables which need to create address rows). A cross join has the same result as my example.
I think I would rather need to rely on returning the new address ids in order and then creating the person table with them, but I do not know how.
I found ways with temporary columns or with setting id ranges - e.g. (id10+1 / id10+2), but I hope Postgresql offers a better way.

Not sure what you're looking for, but multiple INSERTs work fine:
INSERT INTO address(street, city)
SELECT person_1_street, person_1_city
FROM source_data
UNION
SELECT person_2_street, person_2_city
FROM source_data;

INSERT INTO person(name, address_id)
SELECT person_1_name, address.id
FROM source_data
    JOIN address ON person_1_street = street AND person_1_city = city
UNION
SELECT source_data.person_2_name, address.id
FROM source_data
    JOIN address ON person_2_street = street AND person_2_city = city;

SELECT *
FROM person
    JOIN address ON person.address_id = address.id;

If this is not what you're looking for, we need additional examples.

Your solution works, as you (rightfully) expect the address table to have unique addresses, right?
I would have given every person a single address row - this has advantages (e.g. if one person moves out) and disadvantages (if both move, I need to change two addresses).
So in that case (if we give John and Jane the same address) your solution does not work anymore, correct?
Change first set of values in original example to:
values ('John Doe', '123 Main St', 'Springfield', 'Jane Doe', '123 Main St', 'Springfield');

@micha.net what you're describing is more of a semantic issue. If I see an address table, I would assume that this is an isolated source of data for addresses. Meaning the only reason for rows in there to change, is if the address of that house actually changes (e.g. the physical street got renamed). If a person moves, they are no longer at the same address, so I would expect it no longer points at the same address row.

I agree, so maybe not the best example for my problem.
Maybe consider the question in more general terms. Is there a way to "use the ids resulting from the CTE in the following insert, to set a value (as a foreign keys)"?

@micha.net Yes you can, just use the result as from the returning step in the next step of your query. Just JOIN that part
